# Swift navigation bar back button frame breaks

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, navigationbar

I changed font of navigation bar title and back button in AppDelegate following way

```
private func setupNavigationBar() {
    //Navigation Bar
    let attrs: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: FontFamily.Muller.medium.font(size: 17)
    ]
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = ColorName.mainBlue.color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attrs

    let barButtonItemAppearance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
    barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: FontFamily.Muller.regular.font(size: 15)], for: .normal)
    barButtonItemAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font:
        FontFamily.Muller.regular.font(size: 15)], for: .highlighted)
}
```

And it's ok
[image: back button frame ok]

But frame of back button breaks on 3rd screen.
[image: back button frame breaks]

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: are you sure that `Aнкета` doesn't have `\n` at the end of word?

Comment: @gaRik, yes I checked it